# Approximate the sum of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, summation

Let $a_1=1/2$ and $a_{n+1} = a_n^2 + a_n$.

And $$S = \frac{1}{(a_1 + 1)} + \frac{1}{(a_2 + 1)} + .....+ \frac{1}{(a_{100} + 1)}$$  .

We have to find $[S]$ ?

Where
$[x]$ = Greatest Integer less than or equal to $x$.

I can't think of any pattern between the subsequent terms in the sum which would help me to find the sum.

Any hints would be useful.

Comment: Please edit. Does "a n^2" mean $(a_n)^2$ or $a_{(n^2)}$?

Comment: @user254665 It is obviously $a_n^2$, since $a_{n+1}=a_{n^2}+a_n$ does not make sense.

Comment: using a calculator, you can see that $a_8 > 10^8$, and so $a_9 > 10^{16}$, etc. So you can stop your sum at the seventh summand.

Comment: But the terms start getting messy right from the start.   I am looking for a more elegant method...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{a_k+1}=\frac{1}{a_k}-\frac{1}{a_k(a_k+1)}=\frac{1}{a_k}-\frac{1}{a_k^2+a_k}=\frac{1}{a_k}-\frac{1}{a_{k+1}}$$
hence your sum is a telescopic sum:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac{1}{a_k+1} = \frac{1}{a_1}-\frac{1}{a_{101}} $$
and since $a_n\geq n-1$ holds for every $n\geq 4$ (easy to prove by induction), $S$ is just a bit less than $2$.

Comment: What made u think of this factorisation or does it come only by practice ?